# How to see if values in a column changed across multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a table below that I need to see if interest rates changed for any loan number within a given period. Below is just sample data, I need to find this information across 2 million rows. How can this be done?

**Sample data**

```
+------------+-------------+---------------+
|    DATE    | LOAN_NUMBER | INTEREST_RATE |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
| 04/01/2010 |     1111122 | 0.375         |
| 05/15/2011 |     1111122 | 0.375         |
| 06/01/2012 |     1111122 | 0.300         |
| 07/08/2010 |     1111133 | 0.400         |
| 07/01/2011 |     1111133 | 0.450         |
+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I tried to do the following:

```
Select A.Date, A.Loan_Number, A.Interest_Rate
FROM TABLEX A
INNER JOIN TABLEX B ON A.Loan_Number = B.Loan_Number
AND A.Date < B.Date
```

But this does not get me the results I need.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a row_number to imitate next function like

```
   select b.* 
    from (
    Select [Date], Loan_Number, Interest_Rate,row_number() over(partition by Loan_Number order by  [Date] desc, Interest_Rate desc) rowid
    FROM TABLEX)  A
    join (
    Select [Date], Loan_Number, Interest_Rate,row_number() over( partition by Loan_Number order by  [Date] desc, Interest_Rate desc) rowid
    FROM TABLEX)  B
    on a.rowid = b.rowid -1 
    and a.Loan_Number = b.Loan_Number
    where a.Interest_Rate <> b.Interest_Rate
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  "multiple date"  "date period"

Comment: OK I still don't think that is the question

Comment: I will test this out when i'm in tomorrow to see if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.Date, A.Loan_Number, A.Interest_Rate 
     , B.Date, B.Interest_Rate 
FROM TABLEX A
INNER JOIN TABLEX B 
 ON A.Loan_Number = B.Loan_Number
AND DateDiff(dd, A.Date, B.Date) =< 10 
AND DateDiff(dd, A.Date, B.Date)  > 0
AND A.INTEREST_RATE <> B.INTEREST_RATE
```

Answer (score 0):

`Interest_Rate` has changed means that `MIN` value is not the same as `MAX` value.

The query would return a list of all `Loan_Numbers` for which the `Interest_Rate` has changed within the given period (from `@StartDate` inclusive till `@EndDate` exclusive).

```
SELECT A.Loan_Number
FROM TABLEX A
WHERE
    A.Date >= @StartDate
    AND A.Date < @EndDate
GROUP BY A.Loan_Number
HAVING MIN(A.Interest_Rate) <> MAX(A.Interest_Rate)
;
```